# Did Chrome os lose its file services with version 96?

Tags: google-chrome-os

Previously you could 'add services' in the file manager, in order to add a sort of 'driver' to Dropbox, OneDrive etc... This 'add services' option seems to have disappeared in version 96.

Did you notice ? Is there a new method / extension / workaround for that ?

Comment: Which file manager? Did you look for apps?

Comment: @music2myear I speak about the standard Chrome OS 'Files' app.

Answer (score 1):

The new solution is to install the Android app of the desired service, and use that to connect to the service.
After a reboot, Files will provide access to that cloud data.
I tried with OneDrive, and it worked like a charm. Did not try with Dropbox, since they now limit you to 3 devices with the free account :(

Solution provided by https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/rkw5ow/comment/hpcn223/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3
(and YES, I did crosspost for once...and Reddit was way more responsive)